# How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?

Tags: html, embed, flash

How do you embed a SWF file in an HTML page?

Answer (score 175, accepted):

The best approach to embed a SWF into an HTML page is to use [SWFObject](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/).

It is a simple open-source JavaScript library that is easy-to-use and standards-friendly method to embed Flash content.

It also offers Flash player version detection. If the user does not have the version of Flash required or has JavaScript disabled, they will see an alternate content. You can also use this library to trigger a Flash player upgrade. Once the user has upgraded, they will be redirected back to the page.

An example from the documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

A good tool to use along with this is the SWFObject HTML and JavaScript [generator](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject/wiki/SWFObject-Generator). It basically generates the HTML and JavaScript you need to embed the Flash using SWFObject. Comes with a very simple UI for you to input your parameters.

It Is highly recommended and very simple to use.

Comment: SWFObject is good. It simply works. An even more wonderful idea is to use a Content Delivery Network to get the javascript. I use Google's https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js

Comment: I had problems with using the object tag directly with IE9 but it works perfectly with swfobject.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now can you suggest a player as well for accessing playback capability along with working example in html itself. ????

Comment: Can this is work on that system where flash player is not install or it support all browsers.

Comment: The project is now moved to GitHub: https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject and the new technique to embed swf object is `var el = document.getElementById("my-target-element");
swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", el, 300, 120, 10);`

Comment: swfobject no longer works properly with Chrome. Chrome new policy (HTML by default) is unrolled starting at version 55 and no longer initializes the variables that swfobject needs to test if Flash is installed. swfobject may give an incorrect message 'install flash' when in reality Flash is simply being blocked by Chrome, causing confusion for the user. For Chrome, the best course of action may be to simply use <object> to embed Flash.

Comment: Note: This answer is over 10 years old and very out of date. This doesn't play nicely with Chrome anymore as @Chris mentions. Please see some of the much better HTML5 answers. They are simple and supported directly by browser vendors and don't require downloading the swfobject library for your users.

Answer (score 130):

```
<object width="100" height="100">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
    <embed src="file.swf" width="100" height="100">
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: That code isn't XHTML-valid ... <embed> must not be within a object-tag.

Comment: No specification of the user to be XHTML valid, he asked for HTML

Comment: this article have a good explanation about embedding flash and valid XHTML. http://yoast.com/articles/valid-flash-embedding/

Comment: why not use `data` attribute in [<object>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element) element? Quote from w3c html5 docs: _At least one of either the data attribute or the type attribute **must** be present._

Comment: @JokoWandiro the link your provided is unfortunately gone. Here's an archived version: https://web.archive.org/web/20180602024700/https://yoast.com/must-reads-for-website-seo/valid-flash-embedding/

Answer (score 19):

How about simple HTML5 tag embed?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<embed src="anim.swf">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

This is suitable for application from root environment.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/dir/application.swf" 
id="applicationID" style="margin:0 10px;width:auto;height:auto;">

<param name="movie" value="/dir/application.swf" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" /> <!-- Or opaque, etc. -->

<!-- ↓ Required paramter or not, depends on application -->
<param name="FlashVars" value="" />

<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />

</object>
```

Additional parameters should be/can be added which depends on .swf it self. **No embed**, just **object** and parameters within, so, it remains valid, working and usable everywhere, it doesn't matter which !DOCTYPE is all about. :)

Answer (score 8):

If you are using one of those js libraries to insert Flash, I suggest adding plain object embed tag inside of `<noscript/>`.

Answer (score 8):

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/VhtIydTmOVU&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;color1=0xe1600f&amp;color2=0xfebd01" 
style="width:640px;height:480px;margin:10px 36px;">

<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/VhtIydTmOVU&amp;hl=en&amp;fs=1&amp;color1=0xe1600f&amp;color2=0xfebd01" />
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="menu" value="false" />

</object>
```

Comment: Note that object>data and movie>value parameters are the same. This code should work for any free to watch and share - youtube video.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's desirable for answers to explain the code they give, rather than just dropping code on the asker. The goal is to learn about problems and prevent them in the future rather than make them vanish.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://wiltgen.net/objecty/, it helps to embed media content and avoid the IE "click to activate" problem.

Comment: The "click to activate" problem is called "eolas activation" but is removed in actual versions of the IE.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned SWF Object is great. [UFO](http://osflash.org/doku.php?id=ufo) is worth a look as well

Answer (score 2):

This one will work, I am sure!

```
<embed src="application.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getfashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="690" height="430">
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the 'best' way? Words like 'most efficient,' 'fastest rendering,' etc. are more specific. Anyway, I am offering an alternative answer that helps me most of the time (whether or not is 'best' is irrelevant).

Alternate answer: Use an iframe.

That is, host the SWF file on the server. If you put the SWF file in the root or public_html folder then the SWF file will be located at `www.YourDomain.com/YourFlashFile.swf`.

Then, on your index.html or wherever, link the above location to your iframe and it will be displayed around your content wherever you put your iframe. If you can put an iframe there, you can put an SWF file there. Make the iframe dimensions the same as your SWF file. In the example below, the SWF file is 500 by 500.

Pseudo code:

```
<iframe src="//www.YourDomain.com/YourFlashFile.swf" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

The line of HTML code above will embed your SWF file. No other mess needed.
Pros: W3C compliant, page design friendly, no speed issue, minimalist approach. 
Cons: White space around your SWF file when launched in a browser.

That is an alternate answer. Whether it is the 'best' answer depends on your project.

Comment: for google @Stoic sorry your wrong it should be `//www...` using `//` means that if your on HTTPS or HTTP it works using the same connection type

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question. But this answer will be good for the present.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>histo2</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffff99;}
        body { margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; }
        #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashContent">
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="histo2.swf" width="822" height="550" id="histo2" style="float: none; vertical-align:middle">
                <param name="movie" value="histo2.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffff99" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                </a>
            </object>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thi works on IE, Edge, Firefox, Safari and Chrome.

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="movie.swf" width="720" height="480">
  <param name="movie" value="movie.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
  <param name="play" value="true" />
  <param name="loop" value="true" />
  <param name="wmode" value="window" />
  <param name="scale" value="showall" />
  <param name="menu" value="true" />
  <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
  <param name="salign" value="" />
  <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
  <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
  </a>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    <a target="_blank" href="{{ entity.link }}">
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="{{ entity.file.path }}?clickTAG={{ entity.link }}" width="120" height="600" style="visibility: visible;">
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="play" value="true">
            <param name="LOOP" value="false">
            <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="true">
        </object>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<embed>` element:

```
<embed src="file.swf" width="854" height="480"></embed>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JavaScript if you're familiar with, like that:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("filename.swf", "Title", "width", "height", "9.0.0");
```

--the 9.0.0 is the flash version.

Or you can use the `<object>` tag of HTML5.

Comment: -1 swfobject isn't just part of JavaScript, you can't just call it without embedding the library. and most of the functionality for the <object> tag has been stripped out from HTML 4 to 5. It can still be used, but not recommended. All in all a very bad answer.

Comment: did you already tried it before saying its a very bad answer? keep in mind that very bad answer, is the answer that don't totally work or wrong.

Comment: the fact that you're informing someone to use javascript, and then pasting code using a javascript library that you haven't even mentioned makes it a bad answer

Comment: I already mentioned to used Javascript and gave the script. If I gave the whole working code/script that makes a spoonfeeding. The script is fine its only a logic.

Comment: You're misunderstanding my comment. You haven't told him to include the SWFObject Javascript file