# How to embed a swf file into html code?

Tags: html, flash

I need to embed a swf file into html code. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to embed a SWF file in a html page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page)

Comment: this site is not ideal for asking this sort of questions. Please take a look at our FAQ. http://stackoveflow.com/faq

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use SWFObject:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>SWFObject dynamic embed - step 3</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    swfobject.embedSWF("myContent.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0");
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myContent">
      <p>Alternative content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you posted this, it was correct but SWFObject is now deprecated. So developers would be better to look at the answer from @denislexic

Comment: @brianlmerritt Developers would be better to not use Flash at all these days.

Comment: Absolutely, but some sites still do - it's a pain!

Comment: @brianlmerritt Sure, and if you're still using Flash, you'll still have no problems with SWFObject.  It's as useful now as it was before.

Comment: Let's let future visitors make up their iwb minds. Hopefully no one else will end up here, but if they do there is now a comment trail that they can follow...

Answer (score 9):

From w3school

```
<object width="550" height="400">
   <param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
   <embed src="somefilename.swf" width="550" height="400">
   </embed>
</object>
```

More info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/flash/flash_inhtml.asp)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, W3Schools is considered to be a very poor source of information and referencing it is frowned upon here.  I won't downvote you for it, but others might.

Comment: @david I disagree with you. You can see its reputation over the internet. W3schools is really good for HTML/CSS information.

Comment: @imran tariq: I can see its popularity, but can you cite a source for its reputation?  Regardless, in at least this community it's highly discouraged.  For reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource

Comment: @david I'll make a note of it.  Thanks.

Comment: I'll vote you up for w3schools. I often use it as quick reference when I need something. I don't learn there but it keeps the things for me I don't want to or can't remember?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [flashobject](http://blog.deconcept.com/flashobject/). It's a Javascript utility that will detect whether the plugin is installed in a cross browser way and replace a given div with the flash object you want.

**Update**. I see someone else has posted a link to SWFObject. That's what I was looking for when I posted this. You should use that instead. It's more actively developed and maintained.