# Make asp.net site more attractive by flash template

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

I have downloaded a free flash template from http://www.flashmo.com/preview/flashmo_197_bokeh

I want to use this template in my **asp.net (C#)** website. More specifically speaking, I want to use that color effect ( the color-change that is happening there in the background of the page) in my webpage.. Please help me to do so..

(Please do check the link I have provided. It will help you understand the color-change I am talking about).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the colour change on the actual background image or the darker frame that surrounds the text?

Comment: The colour change on the actual background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fairly straight forward.

Just embed the downloaded swf file in the aspx page as you would with a regular html page.

See an example on: [How to embed a swf file into html code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705981/how-to-embed-a-swf-file-into-html-code)

The hard part is going to be interacting with the swf. This is possible via Javascript, but is gona take some work. In flash action script you can expose variables to javascript. Once that is done, you can call asp.net code from javascript. Both techniques are very well documented on the net. Just google on it.

Good luck ...

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use flash to create a website and don't use 'attractive' to describe a website.