# FLV Player not works in IE Browser?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, swfobject

I have the following piece of code which play the flv file,

```
<embed align="middle" width="185" height="121" 
    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true"
    allowscriptaccess="sameDomain"
    name="vidplayer" bgcolor="#eae7db" quality="high" f
    lashvars="file=<?= $vUrl; ?>" src="scripts/flvplayer.swf" />
```

Above code which works only in FF,chrome not in IE Browser.

Also i refered link [How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page) changed the above code like below,

```
<object width="185" height="121">
    <param name="movie" value="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>scripts/flvplayer.swf">
    <embed align="middle" width="185" height="121"
        pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" 
        allowscriptaccess="sameDomain" name="vidplayer" bgcolor="#eae7db"
        quality="high" flashvars="file=<?= $vUrl; ?>"
        src="scripts/flvplayer.swf" >
    </embed>
</object>
```

This above code works only in FF not in Chrome and IE.

How can i play my flv file in all browsers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
       var flashvars = {};
       var params = {};
       var attributes = {};     
       flashvars.mp3="mast.mp3";
       var so = new swfobject.embedSWF("player.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9.0.0",true, flashvars, params, attributes);
       so.write("myContent");
    </script>
```

and have a look at this [Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation).