# How to embed swf file in CakePHP

Tags: php, html, cakephp, flash

How can I embed a `.swf` file in CakePHP application?

Is there any easy way to embed swf file in my CakePHP `.ctp` file?

Answer (score 2):

Just ignore the fact that it's a CTP file and add it like you would in any other php/html file.  The CTP is just an extension, but it boils down to just being a PHP document.

Some walk-throughs:

[How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page)

http://www.yofla.com/flash/embedding-swf/

...etc  (can Google "how to embed a swf" and get around 6 million examples :)