# Display flash using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I want to change the Flash using the on click command with JavaScript

now, here the button works correctly but the flash does not display...

**JavaScript code**

```
<script>
var count=0;

function mafunct(flash){
var path="a"+count+".swf";  

    flash+='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">';          
    alert(path);
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE='+path+' >';          
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="PLAY" VALUE="false">';  
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="LOOP" VALUE="false">';
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="QUALITY" VALUE="high">';
    flash+='<PARAM NAME="SCALE" VALUE="SHOWALL">';
    flash+='<EMBED NAME="testmovie" SRC="Menu.swf" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%"PLAY="false" LOOP="false" QUALITY="high" SCALE="SHOWALL"swLiveConnect="true"PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/go/flashplayer/">';
    flash+='</EMBED>';
    flash+='</OBJECT>';     
document.write(flash);
count++;

}
</script>
```

**HTML button code**

```
<button onclick="mafunct()">next</button>
```

My flash files are named `a0.swf`,`a1.swf`.... etc

Comment: is it video? or something else in flash

Comment: Why do you alert() the flash string instead of appending it to the document?

Comment: it's just a flash video file

Comment: ok just update the question

Comment: refer this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page), here you will get your all answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove:

```
alert(path);
```

Change the:

```
alert(flash);
```

to:

```
document.write(flash);
```

Comment: thanx for answer... how it is dynamically  change flash one by one

Comment: You want to have multiple flash objects on a page or just one that changes on button click?

Comment: i have multiple flash files and changes on one by one on a button click ... and the name of flash files are a0.sef,a1.swf..etc

Comment: I understood that, but what do you want to achieve... to show them all on button click (one after another) OR to show one by one after each button click OR to show one, then remove that one after clicking the button again and showing another?

Comment: What does it do now? try this:
    var flash ='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">';

replace first "flash +=" with "var flash ="

Comment: i just use this code <script>
var count=0;function mafunct(flash){ 
var path="a"+count+".swf"; 
var flash ='<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" CODEBASE="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">'; 

 but the flash not change