# Is this a safe way to show .swf files?

Tags: security, flash, swfobject

Hello currently I am showing some .swf files inside my website but I don't know if I have left any case for potential security flaws or if the way I am using the swf files isnt correct for all browsers or slows down the page not sure if im doing it right.

This is the code I have now:

```
<object width="200" height="300" data="album.swf"></object>
```

I read on this post: [How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page)

I am puzzled because the above method mentioned on the post appears to slow down the website with the javascript calling and all.

What is your opinion? Why do they use swfobject?

Edit: Is this correct?

```
<embed allowScriptAccess="never" allownetworking="none" src="album.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" quality="high" width="750" height="463" name="Album" />
```

Thank you!

Comment: The object/embed tags are the ONLY way to show a SWF file in a browser. In the end SWFObject does the same thing, however, it gives you various approaches to embedding the SWF. I've never noticed that SWFObject affected performance of page loading or javascript execution in general. If you're still interested in SWFObject, I'd create another question that describes the issues you encountered with it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is it best to use only the embed like I did in the example above or also the object before?

Comment: You need to use both. The `<object>` tag is needed for embedding a SWF in IE, and the `<embed>` tag is needed for all the other browsers.