# How to include swf file on a page

Tags: html, flash, swfobject, swfupload, swfloader

I want to know if I have a lot of games in swf format and I want them to be embedded in  html,  what is the tag for doing it?

```
<object width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
    ..
    <embed src="intro.swf" width="100%" height="100%" />
</object>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page

Comment: I had problems with using the object tag directly with IE9 but it works perfectly with swfobject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sample code if you have **sample.swf** file

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="50" height="50" id="FlashID" title="sample">
  <param name="movie" value="sample.swf" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
  <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
  <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
  <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
  <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
  <!--[if !IE]>-->
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="sample.swf" width="50" height="50">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
    <div>
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
  </object>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
swfobject.registerObject("FlashID");
//-->
</script>
```

you also need to include below JavaScript file http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js

Comment: swfobject isn't just part of JavaScript, you can't just call it without embedding the library. and most of the functionality for the <object> tag has been stripped out from HTML 4 to 5. It can still be used, but not recommended. All in all a very bad answer