# How to pass URL to UrlRequest properly in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a file `abc.swf` embed in a html file called `index.html`

The SWF file needs to access `abc.xml`

The `abc.xml` is stored in `Rooms/abc.xml`

The `index.html` is stored in `Schedule/index.html`

In the `abc.swf`, I have code:

```
inforequest=new URLRequest("~/Rooms/abc.xml");
```

However I got an error:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error
```

I know this is because the URL is wrong but I dont know how to fix that.
I've tried: `Rooms/abc.xml, abc.xml, ../Rooms/abc.xml` but none of them worked.
Please help!

**EDIT:**

This is the html file:

```
@model Booking_Ticket_Management_System.Models.Schedule

@{
ViewBag.Title = "XmlGenerate";
}

<h2>Choose your seats</h2>
<object width="500" height="600">
<param name="movie" value="~/Rooms/@Url.Content(Model.Room.Map)"/>
<embed src="~/Rooms/@Url.Content(Model.Room.Map)" width="500" height="600"/>
</object>
```

Comment: I would also suggest to actually listen to the `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` and dont let it throw errors to the user.

Comment: Finally, I got it right. Thank you for your answer. I didnt handle the IOErrorEvent. Thats why it didnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get into habit to always add at least 2 listeners: Complete - which normally is added by all, and IOErrorEvent which normally is skipped by all:)

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();

    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderHandler, false, 0, true);
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderHandler, false, 0, true);

    loader.load(new URLRequest("path/to/image.jpg"));

//...
protected function libLoadHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    var loader:Loader = (e.target as LoaderInfo).loader;
    if(e.type == Event.COMPLETE || e.type == IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR)
    {
        //unregister both as COMPLETE and IO_ERROR are "finishing" events
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaderHandler, false);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, loaderdHandler, false);

        //do something after event based on event type
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this,

```
var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../abc.xml");
```

Comment: It means I have to use absolute Url. Is there any way to use relative Url?

Comment: If you want to use relative Url, try like  this var myRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("../abc.xml");

Comment: When I used absolute Url and placed the swf file into the same folder as the html file then I run swf file, it worked, but if I run the html file, it didnt work. I dont know why.

Comment: did you embed SWF file in that HTML page?

Comment: else try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page

Comment: where is your abc.swf file?

Comment: I used "~/Rooms/@Url.Content(Model.Room.Map)" to get the swf file from database. It showed the swf file incorrectly as the swf file didnt recognize the xml file because of the Url path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52653/discussion-between-tung-pham-and-shankar)