# Embedded swf does not play - Using IIS

Tags: html, onclick, flash

I have a SWF file called myswf.swf...

If i Drag and Drop the file into my Browser, it runs normaly and i can click buttons in it.

But if i embed this SWF file with this code:

```
<object width="850" height="688">
  <embed src="myswf.swf" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"   width="850" height="688"></embed>
</object>
```

it displays the swf file and "mouse of buttons" works but i cant click the buttons (nothing happens if i click a button).

i also included the "swfobject.js" but doesnt do anything.

Is my problem understandable?

Thx for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the example from documentation:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation

and at this thread:

[How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/best-way-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But the problem was soemthing else.

Iam using IIS and the SWF file includes an .F4V file. The problem was that the IIS didnt have had the MIME-TYPE for the .F4V file. so it displays the SWF but cant play it becouse of the missing MIME-TYPE for the .F4V.

To solve this i teached the IIS the .F4V MIME-TYPE...and done it works now