# How can i embed a swf file on a google site and make it playable?

Tags: flash, embed

How can i embed a swf file on a google site and make it playable? I need help with this because i am trying to make a game website. please pm me if you can help or know the answer to my problem.

Comment: what do you mean, "google site"? you wan to hack google.com and force everyone who searches to view your video? or a google-hosted site, e.g. app engine?

Comment: i used google sites to make a website and i want to embed a swf game.

Comment: Whats wrong with **[these google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+sites+%22swf+embed%22)**? Try something and show your code that's not working for you

Comment: Because none of them make sense to me. Because im kind of new with html

Comment: really? Even **[this link](https://sites.google.com/site/matgablertech/internet/google-sites/embed-flash-swf)** is confusing? Ask an HTML capable friend to help you out with it. As for new to HTML then you better practice first then ask when truly stuck. Make a test folder on your computer drive and put the SWF file there, make a blank **.html** using a text editor (like Windows **NotePad**) and start looking at tutorials to embed a SWF into webpage. Paste and test those examples into your new text file (saved as .html) and open in browser... works? great else try again...

Comment: Thanks that is helpful. If i give you permissions can you help me?

Comment: it didnt work @VC.One

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/d5live.net/gamesatschool/thingthing3 @VC.One

Comment: What are you saying? Dont offer a stranger your passwords to login anywhere. I told you to practice embedding SWF into an html file that is running from your hardrive. Look at tutorials using SWFObject. Test in multiple browsers just in case your code works in some. Later when you get it, then try with files from Google Sites instead of hard drive.

Comment: Yeah but i need you to help me. And i can give your google account permission to edit the website. @VC.One

Comment: It's not my place to edit your website. Look at how to make a basic webpage (with `Head` and `Body` sections)?. The **[second link](http://www.goopal.org/Google-Sites-Embed/flash-embed/google-sites-swf)** in those google results I mentioned 7 days ago show you how to embed `<object>`. that code in box goes in the `Body` section of your html file. So paste, save it as mypage.html and open that mypage with browser. If really struggling, just check this **[Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/137349/2057709)** and that file **swfobject.js** from link, must be saved same place as your html file

Comment: @VC.One i am new at html so can you give me the example code?

Comment: Did you try this **[code in Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/how-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-a-html-page?rq=1)**? There is no need to copy and paste it. On your Question post there is a small "edit" button. Update it to show your SWF link and the html code you tried in there...