# How to correctly deploy a FLEX\FLASH swf application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

I am absolutly new in **Flex** and **Flash** and I have the following problem.

I have to work on a **Flex 4** project made by someone else in the past using the Eclipse plugin and building it using an **ANT** script (but I think that this is not so important).

After that I run my ANT script it build my project into this **target** folder:

[image]

So, as you can see in the previous image, the building project have created the **target** content corresponding to the **Main.swf** file (that I think is the Flex\Flash application), the **asset** directory (that contains some resources used by the application: fonts, incos, images and CSS) and the **flexmonster** directory that should contains something related to a library that generates table.

My problem is: now how can I deploy this application?

I saw this video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0YTZm1v7qQ&t=326s

but in this tutorial show that the project generates also an html that is linked to the **swf** file (but doesn't show the HTML content, in the tutorial seems to be autogenerated).

How can I try to execute my application? (into the browser)

Are there some difference in the deploy of a Flex and Flash application or are the same thing?

Comment: Your project has a back end, or has been implemented only with front end?

Comment: @JoeTaras It have to be connected to a Java back end, why? what change?

Comment: Is not mandatory I asked for you about consider your development context. So if you use Flash Builder IDE, iyou can click on Run button your app should be started on browser.

Comment: @JoeTaras hehe I don't know to much about the context because I am here only from 3 days and I am working on an old application by someone else in the bast. Anyway...no I am not using Flash Builder, we use the Eclipse plugin for Flex development, the project contains an ANT script that execute the build of my process and populate the previous target directory. The Flex project interact in some way with the Java back end application running on a Tomcat server (but I really yet don't know how the front end and back end comunicate because I yet don't know anything about Flex...I am a Java dev)

Comment: Ok, have you tried to copy your swf under web server folder? An example, suppose you have a Java web project named firstapplication, you must copy your swf under that folder

Comment: Communication between front end and back end, when Flex is envolded, is managed by Blaze DS or Life Cycle connector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should:

1. embed the swf, see: [How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/how-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-an-html-page)
2. transfer the files inside the `target` folder (including the embedded html for example) onto your server.

But you should ask in your company how they embed the swf, may it is delivered from the JAVA-application and not in plain HTML.

Answer (score 3):

To correctly deploy a Flash or Flex web app you require to:

1. Create an HTML file which will embed your .swf file using SWFObject.
2. The SWFObject JS library.
3. Put those two files in your 'target' folder, then upload the 'target' folder to your web server.

Here's a quick tip for steps 1 and 2:

1. In Flash Builder you are going to see at the top a button with an icon that looks like a globe with an orange arrow, it is the Release Build button. Press it.
2. Flash Builder is going to generate a very similar folder to your 'target' folder. Copy and paste the .html and .js file into your 'target' folder.
3. Now you can upload your 'target' folder to your web server (via FTP or admin panel).

Answer (score -1):

Just copy target folder files to your production web location.