# How can I insert a .swf into an html page?

Tags: html, flash, blogger

Im using blogger and I wanted it to be able to play some swf games I made. How can I add them? I tried searching but I couldnt find anything,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to embed a SWF file in an HTML page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137326/how-to-embed-a-swf-file-in-an-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

HTML has an 'embed' tag built in: e.g. `<embed src="helloworld.swf">`. More information can be found at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_embed_src.asp)

Comment: I used the embed tag, with the height width type and src, but it still doesnt work. Its 640x480. when i run it a see a blank window with that scale. Does Dropbox work for the src?

Comment: When I right click the window it also says "movie not loaded..."

Comment: <html>
<body>

<embed height="480" src="Wheel Land v11.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640"></embed>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Try without the closing embed tag: like this `<embed height="480" src="Wheel Land v11.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640">` and make sure the swf file is in your root folder where your html file is.

Comment: It still doesnt work. The swf is a game, but i think it reads it as a movie; could that be it?

Comment: which browser are you using

Comment: Try this code using Google Chrome: `<html><body><embed src="Wheel Land v11.swf" height="480" width="640"></body></html>`

Comment: You can also use object tag like this `<object width="640" height="480" data="Wheel Land v11.swf"></object>` If it still does not work make sure you have the latest Flash player installed.